# How add a value from select/dropdown list to my Prepare Statement?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

First question here but I have been teaching myself PDO over the past few days to integrate into a site I'm developing and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I have been trying to use GET to retrieve the selection from a dropdown menu in order to limit the results displayed from a query.

Here is my code so far

HTML:

```
<form action="searchfx.php" method="get">
<p>Provider Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
<p>Provider Number: <input type="text" name="prvdrnum" /></p>
<p>Number of results to display:</p> <select name="disp" size="1">
<option name="10" value="10">10</option>
<option name="25"value="25">25</option>
<option name="50" value="50">50</option>
</select>
<p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
include("link.php");
$name=$_GET['name'];
$num=$_GET['prvdrnum'];
if(isset($_GET['disp']){
$disp=$_GET['disp'];
}
$query = $link->prepare("SELECT * 
FROM hcisip 
WHERE providerName LIKE '%$name%' 
AND providerNum LIKE '%$num%'
LIMIT 0, $disp"); 
//<------The 50 is what I am trying to change to have the $disp selection

$query -> bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query -> bindValue(':num', $num, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query -> bindValue(':disp', $disp, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
// Display search result
if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
echo "Search found :<br/>";
echo "<table>"; 
echo "<tr><td>Provider Name</td><td>Provider Number</td></tr>";             
while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
echo "<tr><td>";            
echo $results['providerName'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $results['providerNum'];
echo "</td></tr>";              
echo "</table>";
}       
} else {
echo 'Nothing found';
}
?>
```

Basically what I am trying to do here is take the value from the selection box (named "disp" in the html) and add it to the second parameter of the prepared statement (which to my understanding is the upper limit to how many results are displayed.

So far I have tried adding $disp=$_GET['disp']; to the top and then changing the prepared statement to:

$query = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM hcisip WHERE providerName LIKE '%$name%' 
                        AND providerNum LIKE '%$num%' LIMIT 0, '%$disp%'");

but upon doing this my search returns no results ("Nothing Found").

How can I allow the user to select the number of results returned by the query?

I apologize if this is a common question and can assure you I scoured google as I'm sure this is an easy fix/syntax error but I had no success finding a relative topic.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have modified the code above to reflect the changes but am still recieving "Nothing found" which means :disp is not doing its job.

I am also receiving this error:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

EDIT: It's working now, I have edited the code above to reflect my changes. I chose not to enclose the entire block in the if(isset()) statement as I wanted the user to be able to search by any of the fields as opposed to filling in them all.

Comment: Use `CONCAT` to surround your parameters with the `%` wildcard ~ http://pastebin.com/PDVPM9aw

Comment: @Habitat you got some advance?

Comment: @Habitat if my answer was usefull to you don't forget check as correct ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must check that the values in $_GET exists:

EDIT:

```
<?

include("link.php");

if(isset($_GET['disp']) && isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['prvdrnum'])) {
$disp=$_GET['disp'];
$name=$_GET['name'];
$num=$_GET['prvdrnum'];

$query = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM hcisip WHERE providerName LIKE '%$name%' AND providerNum LIKE '%$num%' LIMIT 0, $disp"); 
$query->execute();
// Display search result
if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
 echo "Search found :<br/>";
 echo "<table>"; 
 echo "<tr><td>Provider Name</td><td>Provider Number</td></tr>";             

 while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
  echo "<tr><td>";            
  echo $results['providerName'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $results['providerNum'];
  echo "</td></tr>";              
  echo "</table>";
  }       
 } else {
  echo 'Nothing found';
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: Awesome, I knew it was simple. Also the & was a type - o from putting the code on SO, but nonetheless thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually it seems that after making the changes you suggest that I still receive no results and on top of that am now getting this error: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens     

This seems to be directly related to using the colon syntax as opposed to the $ in the prepared statement as well as the parameter where the upper limit for # of results is.

Comment: @Habitat check this $query -> bindParam(':prvdrnum', $num, PDO_PARAM_STR); you don't change correctly to $query->bindParam(':num', $num, PDO::PARAM_STR); as I write in my answer

Comment: @Habitat see my Edit, you have an error in your html

Comment: Sorry I had changed it offline and not here, still did not make a difference.

Comment: @Habitat you continue with $disp=&_GET['disp']; see my edit please is $disp=$_GET['disp']; What is the problem now? Check your database with the query to see if there is a values to show

Comment: Like I said, the changes you suggested have been properly implemented offline, the & sign was a mistake from transferring my code. The changes you suggested cause the error I posted above with the $query->execute() statement and using the : sign instead of $ for the variables in the SQL prepared statement cause the output of the query to be "Nothing found" which I imagine is from :disp not properly changing the upper limit at LIMIT 0, :disp. The changes you suggested for the prepare statement appear to completely break the query.

Comment: @Habitat I edit the code try now and tell what happens